# PhoneGap config.xml - adding plugins not working

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I'm trying to develop an app for iOS and Android using PhoneGap, but am faced with a problem I cannot seem to find an answer for. It's probably a newbie mistake but maybe someone can point me in the right direction. Here's my environment:

1) PhoneGap version is 6.5.0. Cordova version I just upgraded to 7.0.0.

2) OS X El Capitan (10.11).

3) PhoneGap Developer App installed on iPhone running iOS 10.

4) Hello World example application (but it fails with my real app as well in the same way).

The issue is that if I add a new plugin to config.xml, located at the project root folder, then I see the plugin gets downloaded into the plugins folder, but I can't ever get an instance of it after the deviceready event has fired.

For instance, if I add this to config.xml:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ace" spec="https://github.com/microsoft/ace.git" />
```

If the app gets served up to my iPhone using either the PhoneGap desktop app or the CLI command "phonegap serve", and I alert out window.ace in the deviceready handler, the value is "undefined".

However, if I execute "cordova run ios" to run the app through the simulator, then window.ace is defined and working.

Also, if I change the content src attribute to point to another file, again it works with "cordova run ios", but not with the PhoneGap developer app, which always seems to serve up index.html. I've seen a post from a user who had the same problem there, and the suggestion was that the developer app does not read config.xml. I have proved this is not the case, by deliberately putting errors in there, which are caught.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong, because if I cannot add plugins, it kind of makes the PhoneGap developer app useless?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to install the plugin using npm. Then specify it in config file like:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ace" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
```

**Note**: spec attribute may vary.

The following URLs might be of some help.

- http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/05/26/npm-plugins-available/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugins

Comment: I did it that way for other plugins. Maybe the ace one was a bad example. Anyway, it made no difference. I'm reading that the PhoneGap developer app uses its own config.xml and this might be the reason. Maybe someone can confirm.

Comment: Just to add more info. I have tried this approach for cordoba-plugin-ace and cordoba-plugin-keyboard. In both cases I used "cordova plugin add" to add the plugin. Both fail to instantiate their object when run through the PhoneGap developer app. Both work when using cordova run ios. Both work when connecting to the PhoneGap server through a browser. So circumstantial evidence suggests there is an issue with the PhoneGap developer app installed on devices.

Comment: I also checked the developer app version history on the app store. There are plenty of entries for adding this and that plugin. So I think the right answer is that the developer app uses its own config.xml on the device, which really makes it almost useless for developing real world apps.